# How to exclude blade files from git diff command?

Tags: laravel, git, grep

I have below command to get files and I want to exclude all **.blade.php** files.

```
$(git diff --cached --name-only --diff-filter=ACM | grep ".php\{0,1\}$")
```

How can I do that?

I tried these ways :

1. ```
   $(git diff --cached --name-only --diff-filter=ACM | grep --exclude="*\.blade.php*"| grep ".php\{0,1\}$")
   ```
2. ```
   $(git diff --cached --name-only --diff-filter=ACM | grep --exclude="*\.blade.php*" ".php\{0,1\}$")
   ```

but none of the above is working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One is to use `grep -v` to exclude files that match a pattern.

```
git diff --cached --name-only --diff-filter=ACM | grep ".php\{0,1\}$" | grep -v '.blade.php$'
```

The other is to exclude the files in `git diff`.

```
git diff --cached --name-only --diff-filter=ACM -- . ':!*.blade.php' | grep ".php\{0,1\}$"
```

`-- . ':!*.blade.php'` means all files excluding those that match the pattern `*.blade.php` under the current folder.